# React + Tailwind / CSS - Gradient effect on bottom of background image

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, gradient

I've a BG Image and and a normal bg color.
The Image is not repeating, how can i make a smooth transition.
I thought about something like a gradient effect at the bottom of the image.
That's how it is now:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHFXg.jpg)

```
<div>
      <div
        className='min-h-screen bg-gray-700 bg-no-repeat pb-10'
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${settings[0]?.bgImage})`,
        }}
      >
       // Content
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the container div try something like
`<div className='bg-gradient-to-r  from-gray-900 to-indigo-500'> </div>`

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image